# How to add ~/.composer/vendor/bin to $Path?

Tags: php, laravel

On Laravel website (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x), the documentation said after you download the Laravel via composer,

> Make sure to place Composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in your
>   $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system. This
>   directory exists in different locations based on your operating
>   system; however, some common locations include:
>
> macOS: $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin

I'm so confused about how to check for that and how to add `.composer/vendor/bin` to the path. I checked the other answers but I noticed that they are outdated by a few years ago but I'm not sure if they are relative or updated to current versions.

I have homebrew, oh-my-zch, and iterm2 installed on my Mac.

Comment: Edit your `~/.zshrc` file and export the `$PATH` variable: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: What are the steps for that?

Comment: Edit that file and copy paste that line in.

Comment: So I don't need to replace `# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`?

Comment: The `#` symbol is a bash comment, you can leave those lines as they are just there as an example. Place `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` directly below them and save the file. You'll then need to close and reopen your terminal for the change to take effect.

Comment: How do I know if it's working? I tried typing `composer global about` but all I see in first line is `/Users/kristinabressler/.composer`

Comment: I tried to start a new laravel project for the first time but it's not working...